# With AdjustResize LazyColumn TextFields on the bottom won't open keyboard

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-softkeyboard, lazycolumn, android-compose-textfield

Created a LazyColumn with textFields and it seems to have issue with `"android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`parameter.

When clicking a text field that needs to move up so it won't be hidden behind keyboard, causes issues when using `AdjustResize` parameter.  The keyboard will open and then close again. It seems that textfield has lost a focus when ui is doing adjustResize.

Simple code example:

```
LazyColumn(state = rememberLazyListState()) {
    for (i in 1..20) {
            item {
                TextField(value = "item{$i}", onValueChange = {})
            }
    }
}
```

And in AndroidManifest.xml I have

```
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            ...
```

- Demo to show that keyboard is closed just after it opens. (This issue only happens when to click on item that needs adjustment to be visible when keyboard is open)

[image]

- LazyColumn Textfield works correctly without `AdjustResize` focused item will be moved up and everything is fine. The reason why I would like to use AdjustResize is that in my actual app I have undo/redo buttons at the bottom of the screen and I would like to move them up when keyboard is opened, but it seems I need to use `AdjustResize` to make it work, but that brakes textFields.
- So I was wondering how can I make LazyColumn TextFields to work with `AdjustResize`? (I'm using latest compose version: 1.3.1)

Comment: It sounds like you're running into this bug https://issuetracker.google.com/179203700, which actually has several related issues (e.g., https://issuetracker.google.com/195049010). Unfortunately, I'm not sure if there's a good workaround while using AdjustResize.

Comment: Also similar question recently https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74291380/how-to-write-text-into-textfields-in-a-lazycolumn-at-the-bottom-of-the-screen, with a link to another one explained really well on the answer

Comment: Thanks for answers and yes it's duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74291380/, before posting I was looking is there something similar, but somehow I missed this post